# How to match two tags and show image?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, coldfusion

I have a XML file which is like this:

```
<sport id="02">
    <event>Ceremonies</event>
    <discipline>Closing Ceremony</discipline>
    <fromdate>2014-08-03</fromdate>
    <todate>2014-08-03</todate>
    <place>Hampden Park</place>
</sport>

<sport id="03">
    <event>Aquatics</event>
    <discipline>Diving</discipline>
    <fromdate>2014-07-30</fromdate>
    <todate>2014-08-02</todate>
    <place>Royal Commonwealth Pool</place>
</sport>

<venue id="01">
<name>Royal Commonwealth Pool</name>
<image>http://downloads.glasgow2014.com/sites/default/files/styles/lead-listing/public/images/Royal-Commonwealth-Pool-bb6.jpg</image>
<alt>Image of the Royal Commonwealth Pool</alt>
<about>With Arthurs Seat outside and award-winning architecture inside, Edinburghs Royal Commonwealth Pool offers a dramatic setting for the Diving competitions. The original Royal Commonwealth Pool was designed by RMJM Architects in 1967 for the Edinburgh 1970 Commonwealth Games and it was used again for Edinburgh 1986. Owned by City of Edinburgh Council, the venue has undergone major refurbishment, including the upgrading of the diving pool todate meet international standards.</about>
<address>Dalkeith Road</address>
<city>Edinburgh</city>
<postcode>EH16 5BB</postcode>
<telephone>0131 667 7211</telephone>
<email>info.rcp@edinburghleisure.co.uk</email>
<latitude>55.93901</latitude>
<longitude>-3.172781</longitude>
</venue>

<venue id="04">
<name>Hampden Park</name>
<image>http://downloads.glasgow2014.com/sites/default/files/styles/lead-listing/public/images/Hampden-Park-753.jpg</image>
<alt>Image of Hampden Park</alt>
<about>At one time the worlds largest stadium, Glasgows famous Hampden Park will play host todate the Track and Field Athletics competitions and the XX Commonwealth Games Closing Ceremony. Hampden Park is an iconic place not only for Glaswegians, but also for all Scots as it is home todate the national football team.</about>
<address>Hampden Park</address>
<city>Glasgow</city>
<postcode>G42 9BA</postcode>
<telephone>0141 620 4000</telephone>
<email>info@hampdenpark.co.uk</email>
<latitude>55.825973</latitude>
<longitude>-4.252238</longitude>
```

Here is my XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"  version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" media- type="text/html"/> 

<xsl:param name="id">1</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>     
</head>

<body>

<div id="main">
    <br/>
    <h2>Commonwealth Games 2014 Event Information</h2>
    <hr/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/games/sport[@id=$id]"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sport">

<div id="sport">
    <b>Event: </b><xsl:value-of select="event"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <b>Discipline: </b><xsl:value-of select="discipline"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <b>From: </b><xsl:value-of select="fromdate"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <b>To: </b><xsl:value-of select="todate"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <b>Venue: </b><xsl:value-of select="place"/>
    <br/>
</div>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have a list of events which when an event is clicked it brings up a page with those details from the sport section of my XML.

On this page I also want an image of the venue so I want to do something like this:

If in the sport section, the place says 'Hampden Park' then I want it to match the name in the venue section and bring up the image from the image tag.

I am using ColdFusion to generate HTML pages.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: This question is not quite clear. I assume you intend to call XSLT stylesheets using... what? Javascript? Displaying images in response to onclick events is not something you can achieve with XSLT alone.

Comment: How does your XSLT look like?

Comment: Ok I have added my XSLT code to original post.

Comment: I can hardcode an image but if I use an image for Hampden Park then when I bring up the details for the Commonwealth Pool then Hampden Park will still show. I need the correct image to appear for each event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can hardcode an image, this is how you can bring in conditionality. What you are looking for is the `xsl:choose` element, I'd daresay.

This is a simple example of how to output an image to HTML depending on the value of the variable `$id` from your existing stylesheet.

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$id = '01'">
     <xsl:element name="img">
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
           <xsl:value-of select="venue[@id='01']/image"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="alt">
           <xsl:value-of select="venue[@id='01']/alt"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:element name="img">
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
           <xsl:value-of select="venue[@id='04']/image"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="alt">
           <xsl:value-of select="venue[@id='04']/alt"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

**EDIT**: After clarifying the real issue, here you go:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml"  version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes" 
  indent="yes" media-type="text/html"/> 

<xsl:param name="id" select="02"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
     <head>
         <title></title>     
     </head>
     <body>
        <div id="main">
            <br/>
               <h2>Commonwealth Games 2014 Event Information</h2>
               <hr/>
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
     </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="games">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sport[@id=$id]">
  <div id="sport">
      <b>Event: </b><xsl:value-of select="event"/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <b>Discipline: </b><xsl:value-of select="discipline"/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <b>From: </b><xsl:value-of select="fromdate"/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <b>To: </b><xsl:value-of select="todate"/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <b>Venue: </b><xsl:value-of select="place"/>
      <br/>
  </div>

  <div id="image">
     <xsl:element name="img">
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
           <xsl:value-of select="../venue[name=current()/place]/image"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="alt">
           <xsl:value-of select="../venue[name=current()/place]/alt"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:element>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="venue|sport[@id!=$id]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: But how does my page know to bring in that venue image?

All the page knows is the place name from my sport section - I need to say place (in sport section) = name (in venue section)

Comment: Oh and I meant to say that for this University task we can't use any hardcoded data .... that is the problem! 

You have id='04' - thats hardcoded

Comment: Let's clear up things a bit. Note that the XSLT code that generates your HTML page and the code that actually notices events on the page are two entirely separate blocks. In other words, mouse clicks on the page are completely ignored by XSLT. What you really are looking for is e.g. an onclick eventListener for ColdFusion that passes info to an XSLT stylesheet. Right?

Comment: Ok. I use another xslt file and ColdFusion file to generate a list of sports - see here:
http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/8990/4edh.jpg

You can click each of these sports to take you to another page which gives you all the details as in the sport section of my XML. See here:
http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/2096/kdyl.jpg

I need an image for each venue used in these detail pages. But as you can see the images are in the venue section not the sport section.

I am finding this pretty hard to explain.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are wondering how to get XSLT to display an image from a `venue` element that corresponds to the info in the `place` element of the `sport` element you selected?

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to achieve. It needs to correspond to whatever venue is used.

Comment: Alright. One last question before I'll hopefully be able to help you. From your screenshots it seems like the selection of the `sport` element already works fine. If so, do you control this selection with your global parameter $id?

Comment: Yes it does all work fine. And yes I control the selection with $id.

Comment: Yes it works!! Thank you so much, been trying to get it to works for ages. Your help is much appreciated.